# Java spring boot springdoc fail

Tags: spring-boot, springdoc

I'm trying to implement a spring boot rest documentation using springdoc-openapi. I use spring boot 3.0.0.

I add this dependency to my build.gradle:

`implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui', version: '2.0.2'`

When I start my server and go to : `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` or `http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs`

I receive a 404 error.
what am I doing wrong ?

- I followed the tutorial from [www.baeldung.com](http://www.baeldung.com) : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation.
- I've seen that only springdoc v2 can be used with spring boot v3 : https://springdoc.org/v2/.
- I add `springdoc.enable-native-support=true` to my application.properties according to : [Using Springdoc with Spring Boot 3 Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74712624/using-springdoc-with-spring-boot-3-native) but I get this error from JetBrains : [image]
- I tried to change dependencies and googling but nothing changes, I can't get my documentation.

Comment: I don't any problem by following you setup. Could you share your pom.xml/gradle.build? And try adding `debug=true` in application.properties to see any log related to swagger.

Comment: I restarted my computer and it worked. Thanks for our message.